# Kafka Java client Timed out waiting for a node assignment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, virtual-machine, centos7, confluent-platform

I have installed Confluent Platform on a Centos7 VM. It works fine from within the VM's guest OS.
Now I want to connect to Kafka through a Java client from the Host OS which is windows 10. However, the connection is timing out. I dont know if its a configuration issue or if its an issue with the VM image. Can you please help me with this?

I have followed the following URL to install the confluent local on my centos 7 VM.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html

I have followed Scenario 1: Client and Kafka running on the different machines in the following URL to appropriately set the advertised listeners.

https://www.confluent.co.uk/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

I followed the following URL to create a Java client's producer.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/java.html#client-examples-java

I am using VMware Workstation 16 Player to run the Centos 7 VM. I tried the following Network settings by updating the advertised listeners and the Java client's bootstrap.servers property accordingly. In each setting, ping works fine from Host to Guest IP.

- Bridged
- NAT
- Host Only

The Maven command and the corresponding exception stack trace is given below:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample" -Dexec.args="C:/Users/fs/.confluent/java.config test1" -e

[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from maven-default-http-blocker: http://0.0.0.0/joda-time/joda-time/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata joda-time:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): transfer failed for http://0.0.0.0/joda-time/joda-time/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: windows
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 10.0
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 10
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 0
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: windows-x86_64
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< io.confluent:clients-example >--------------------
[INFO] Building clients-example 6.1.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) > validate @ clients-example >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) @ clients-example ---
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\fs255015\examples\clients\cloud\java
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 7976f4f471ba48396482fb10aa644f8dd891812e at timestamp: 1621208548459
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: 6.1.1-post
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) @ clients-example ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) < validate @ clients-example <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ clients-example ---
[2021-05-17 00:42:29,057] INFO AdminClientConfig values:
        bootstrap.servers = [192.168.80.129:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-05-17 00:42:29,483] INFO Kafka version: 6.1.1-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-05-17 00:42:29,491] INFO Kafka commitId: c209f70c6c2e52ae (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-05-17 00:42:29,493] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1621208549483 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-05-17 00:42:59,516] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1621208579511, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208579612) timed out at 1621208579512 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
[2021-05-17 00:43:01,697] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.80.129:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-17 00:43:22,802] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.80.129:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-17 00:43:29,513] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1621208609512, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609613) timed out at 1621208609513 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
[2021-05-17 00:43:29,545] INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-05-17 00:43:29,546] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1621208639513, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
[2021-05-17 00:43:29,637] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2021-05-17 00:43:29,638] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[2021-05-17 00:43:29,661] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics)
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.createTopic (ProducerExample.java:54)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.main (ProducerExample.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow (KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000 (KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await (KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get (KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.createTopic (ProducerExample.java:50)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.main (ProducerExample.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:06 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-17T00:43:30+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project clients-example: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s): Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project clients-example: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.createTopic (ProducerExample.java:54)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.main (ProducerExample.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow (KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000 (KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await (KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get (KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.createTopic (ProducerExample.java:50)
    at io.confluent.examples.clients.cloud.ProducerExample.main (ProducerExample.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1621208609533, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1621208609637) timed out at 1621208609537 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Stick with bridge networking... Did you setup a port forward on 9092 from host to guest?